# Basic Statistics - Quartile for an odd data set

Tags: excel, statistics

I have the following set of data ,

`1000
2000
3000
3000
7000`

I want to get the first and third quartile. The median is 3000. So according to my calculations,

`q1=(1000+2000)/2 = 1500
 q3=(3000+7000)/2 = 5000`

Excel function Quartile `QUARTILE(E22:E26,1)` and `QUARTILE(E22:E26,3)` results q1 = 2000 and q3 = 3000 which i am not able to understand. What logic am i missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal quartile formulae give the term number for the lower and upper quartiles in the sorted data as:-

```
(n+1)/4
```

and

```
3(n+1)/4
```

If you apply these to your data you get 1.5 and 4.5, i.e. the values half way between the first and second, and fourth and fifth, numbers which are 1500 and 5000 as you predict.

Unfortunately Excel's QUARTILE function doesn't do its this way and it's not clear from Microsoft's documentation what QUARTILE does do.

However Microsoft have now provided two separate functions so you have the option of doing it the normal way if you want to.

[image]

The short answer to the question 'What is the difference' is that QUARTILE.EXC excludes the median. For the long answer, see [this](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/why-excel-has-multiple-quartile-functions-and-how-to-replicate-the-quartiles-from-r-and-other-statistical-packages/) very good article.

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative. My question was prompted when attempting to understand the quartile result on R. I got the same result in excel. The article will be very helpful.

Comment: The article was very helpful in explaining the quartile functionality in excel. I do however have a question. I would like to know for Q1 in the data of `2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29` How was 5.5 derived ? I do understand how 2.75 was obtained. I am failing to grasp how was 2.75 used to derive at 5.5 as Q1. Thanks again  Mr Tom.

Comment: The first one is 2.25 but numbering the terms from zero. This gives you an interpolation between 5 and 7 => 5.5. The second one is 2.75 numbering the terms from one. This gives you an interpolation between 3 and 5 => 4.5.

Comment: The fraction part (0.75) gives the interpolation point between 3 and 5 i.e. 3 + 0.75 * (5-3) = 4.5. Another way of looking at it (and what the VBA does) is a weighted mean of 3 and 5 = 3*.25 + 5 * .75 = 4.5.